# Is there an event for hiding for NavigationBar in Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: uwp, windows-10-mobile

In my scenrio, I need to get notification while hiding the NavigationBar in Window 10 Mobile.
Is there any way to find out the visibility change of the NavigationBar in Window 10 Mobile?

Regards,
Srinivasan

Comment: Have you checked the method in my answer? Is that an acceptable answer?

Comment: I confirm that answer of Grace Feng is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Just have a test, it seems on Windows 10 mobile, we can only make the app run in full screen mode to hide the Navigation bar, but problem is when the app is in full screen mode, the status bar in the top will also be hidden.

So if you want to make your app be launched in full screen mode, you can in the `OnLaunched` method:

```
ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.FullScreen;
```

If you want to enter/ exist the full screen mode when the app is running, for example you can in a Button click event code like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ApplicationView view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();

    bool isInFullScreenMode = view.IsFullScreenMode;

    if (isInFullScreenMode)
    {
        view.ExitFullScreenMode();
    }
    else
    {
        view.TryEnterFullScreenMode();
    }
}
```

> Is there any way to find out the visibility change of the NavigationBar in Window 10 Mobile?

Yes, if you used this full screen mode method to hide the navigation bar, you can add handler of [VisibleBoundsChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.visibleboundschanged.aspx) like this:

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBoundsChanged += OnVisibleBoundsChanged;
```

Then you can do your work in the `OnVisibleBoundsChanged` event:

```
private void OnVisibleBoundsChanged(ApplicationView sender, object args)
{
    //TODO:
}
```

AFAIK, there is no other way to hide navigation bar for now, so this method should solve your problem, but the method doesn't work, you can leave a comment to tell us how did you hide the navigation bar.