# botton OS menu overlapping my page Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have developed a tabbed page application with Xamarin.Forms. The OS navigation menu is overlapping my application. Can this menu be hidden?

Attach one screenshot:[image]

My XAML are:
RootTabbedPage:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyTimesheet.MainPage"             
             xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:MyTimesheet.Behaviors"             
             xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:MyTimesheet.ViewModels"
            xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:MyTimesheet.Pages"

           behaviors:CurrentTabChangedBehavior.AttachBehavior="true"
            >
    <TabbedPage.BindingContext>
        <ViewModels:MainViewModel></ViewModels:MainViewModel>
    </TabbedPage.BindingContext>

        <pages:ClientiPage Title="Clienti"/>
        <pages:CommessePage Title="Commesse"/>
        <pages:ConsuntivazioniPage Title="Consuntivazioni"/>


    <!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->
</TabbedPage>
```

My Child page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:MyTimesheet.ViewModels"
             xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:MyTimesheet.Converters"
             xmlns:Ext="clr-namespace:MyTimesheet.Extensions"
             x:Class="MyTimesheet.Pages.ClientiPage">       
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <ViewModels:ClientiViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <StackLayout >
```

...
                    
                    
                        
                            
                                assets\icons\24\24_addsquarebutton.png
                            
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                   ...

```
</ContentPage>
```

I found an example to develop tabbed page on xamaring forum

Comment: What device are you debugging on? What's SO navigation menu? I'm not familiar with that and didn't find anything when searching for it.

Comment: I debugging on winphone, I do not know the techincal name of OS menu

Comment: Where did you get the terminology 'SO menu' from?

Comment: These menu is provided by Operating System (OS) so OS Menu

Comment: There is an option to hide navigationbar when running the app in full screen mode. You can see the example there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39267144/is-there-an-event-for-hiding-for-navigationbar-in-windows-10-mobile

Comment: Could you show us the XAML code?